# How to see live list of syntax errors in WebStorm 7 (or IntelliJ)?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

While editing a JavaScript file, the IDE shows highlights on the lines that have problems and displays the lightbulb when you're on one of those lines.

How can I see a live list of all problems found in the current file (e.g. syntax errors)?

The only way I found so far was to manually run inspection and check the inspection window. That's quite cumbersome. Even the "Problems" section of the Project window updates itself automatically as soon as I change the code (even without saving) - but it doesn't display the actual errors (only which files have errors).

Apparently the IDE knows what errors exist in the file - I just can't find a way to see all of them in a list.

In every other IDE I know, it is a built-in, enabled-by-default, feature: eclipse, visual studio, brackets, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is an [open issue on the IntelliJ family of products](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68854). Please upvote that issue if you feel it is missing as well!